# Logout link in angular 2

Tags: angular

Folks, 
Need your help in below angular 2 application scenario.
I have logout link which needs to invoke method in AuthService.

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/logout']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout</a></li>
```

method in AuthService:

```
//logout
 logout() {
   this.isUserLoggedin = false;
 }
```

How to achieve this? I dont want to create yet a new component just for calling logout. 
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Why not just make it a p-tag or something else, and put a click event that calls the service method? If you need it to look like a link, you can always style it ;)

Comment: click method causes page to refresh.. do you know how to avoid it?

Comment: Show your code related to this, and let's see :)

Comment: you can also try button instead of <a> tag. `<button (click)="logout()"></button>`

Comment: Use anchor tag with 'ng-href' it won't refresh the page

Answer (score 31):

I was wondering the same thing but I ended up creating a LogoutComponent with a blank template and redirecting the user to login after that. The button based logout functionality works but I wanted a logout route link.

**LogoutComponent.ts**

```
@Component({
  template: ''
})

export class LogoutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }

}
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
  { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent}
```

Comment: Don't forgot to add `import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";` and declare `LogoutComponent` in `app.module.ts`

Comment: Usually after clicking on logout, you are redirected to a page acknowledging that. And then allows to login again if desired (or clicked by mistake). Directly navigating to Login will not give an indication about what's happened. User can also be redirected to login based on session expiry, so they would need to know if this is due to explicit action on their part or something else.

Comment: Just thinking about proper way of redirecting post Logout. For example in bank website, you are redirected to a new page acknowledging the successful logout. The user can either re-login on the acknowledgement page or be redirected to the login page via a link.  However, in most cases, its business needs which tell that.

Comment: Correct. You can use short lived session tokens for that.

Comment: This seems actually the best solution for a quite common problem... And i like that it doesn't implement a click on a-tag which doesn't seem semantically right. And doesn't work for keyboard-navigation.

Comment: Perfect! Thank very much for help me.

Comment: The question explicitly asked for a solution that does not require a component...

Comment: @Predrag Agreed but sometimes a different perspective enlightens us as well especially when it solves a common problem.

Comment: The best and the simplest solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a component, you don't have to use one. Just bind click event to a function that logouts the user and redirects to where you want. Remember passing the $event object in order to prevent default behaviour:

```
<li><a href="#" (click)="onClick($event)">(your link content)</a></li>
```

And in the component that renders that menu:

```
onClick(event: Event): void {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevents browser following the link
    // Here you can call your service method to logout the user
    // and then redirect with Router object, for example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Solution for angular 2, for angular 4, use ng-If/Else)

Assuming the links are displayed in main page app.component, have following in the app.component.ts. This successfully displays the Logout link when user is logged in, else displays the Login link (**due to being tied with an Observable rather than static field**)

```
public isUserLoggedIn: boolean = false;

ngOnInit(): void {
    // Setup a subscription so our variable will know the latest status of login
    this._authService.isLoggedIn().subscribe(status => this.isUserLoggedIn = status);
}
```

In html, use this

```
<div>
    <table *ngIf="isUserLoggedIn">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" (click)="logoutClicked($event)" id="logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout</a><br
            /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table *ngIf="! isUserLoggedIn">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a [routerLink]="['/login']" id="login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" aria-hidden="true"></span>Login</a><br
            /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The logoutClicked event will just call the authService's logout method

In order to avoid hitting same method twice, ngSwitch is a better choice, but somehow not able to get it working, although will look as below:-

```
<div [ngSwitch]="IsUserLoggedIn()">
    <a href="#" (click)="logoutClicked($event)" id="logout" *ngSwitchCase="true">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout</a><br />

    <a [routerLink]="['/login']" id="login" *ngSwitchCase="false">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" aria-hidden="true"></span>Login</a>

</div>
```

Comment: The question was about solving this with a /logout route, not a mouse click

Comment: Assuming a user is already logged in, without a link to some route, how would you let the user request for logout ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your route is defined in some XComponent, inside the ngOnInit you can get the last part of the url like so

```
this.route.url.subscribe(data => {
  this.authType = data[data.length - 1].path;
});
```

Now check if this route is logout and call the authService if it is:

```
if (this.authType === 'logout') {
  this.authServie.logout();
}
```

All that goes into the ngOnInit of the component that has the logout route defined. 
This way, you won't need to define an extra Logout component!